# How to extract .7z file using custom action at wix Merge project?

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

> I have created one Merge project using wix.
>
> I have shipped .7z files and after shipped .7z files,I extract .7z file using Custom action.Following code i have used. how to extract .7z file in merge project using wix.

Sample Code :

```
**<Directory Id="dir_Dataagent" Name="DataAgent">

<Component Id="DataAgent" Guid="{5743FBEA-9BA1-4129-AADE-C7972E0EC858}" NeverOverwrite="yes">

 <File Id="file_A991752FF2104DV88C1E85C82743298C" Checksum="yes" Source="..\..\..\ZipFiles\data.7z" /> 

 </Component>
</Directory>

 <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="EXTRACTFILES" After="InstallExecute">(NOT Installed)
</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>**
```

> But above InstallExecutSequence is not working (.7z) file not extracted.please help me how to extract (.7z) files?

Comment: Why are you including a zip file in your install that you instantly unpack? Use the heat tool to automatically generate the wxs needed to include all the files in the zip in your installer. Doing what you're doing will only cause issues you need to work around to properly remove all the files when someone uninstalls your product or wants to repair/modify it.

Comment: Folder size is 3GB. SO i Convert .7z. same code I use normal wix project. Folder successfully extracted but i can't extracted with Merge project.please tell me how to solve this issue.